# I can't find it by class name, and I can't because it keeps changing its position

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://shopping.naver.com/")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("query")
elem.send_keys("hello")
sleep(1)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("subFilter_btn_mall__2HDL4").click()
sleep(2)
**elem = driver.findElement_By_xpath("//label for[@='lb_brand_[n],[인터파크]']").click()**
```

If you type anything other than Hello, the '인터파크' text in the check box changes the location of the class or name. I'd appreciate it if you could tell me the solution.

Comment: By the way, you should probably get rid of your calls to `sleep`, but after you create the driver, call `driver.implicitly_wait(5)` or with even a larger number. When you do a *find* operation, the driver will wait for up to 5 seconds for the element to appear before timing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
driver.get("https://shopping.naver.com/")
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("query")
elem.send_keys("hello")
sleep(3)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
sleep(2)
# Even you can use link_text to click as below element displays as link
driver.find_element_by_link_text("쇼핑몰선택").click()
sleep(2)
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("((//*[text()='인터파크'])[1])")
elem.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this locator

```
//label[contains(text(),'인터파크')]
```

So the command will be

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'인터파크')]").click()
```

Comment: File "c:\Users\KIM DO\Desktop\test01\selenium\google.py", line 14, in <module>
    elem = driver.findElement_By_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'인터파크')]").click()
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'findElement_By_xpath'         　　　　　　　　　                                       Thank you for your answer, but I don't know how to use it, so I'm getting this error...

Comment: @kkkk The answer has been updated with the correct method name.

Comment: It's because YOU are using non-existing method, not what I wrote! The method is `find_element_by_xpath`, not `findElement_By_xpath` !!!